# Is there a function or method to erase the content of a file mapping without closing it?

Tags: c++, windows, ipc

I'm working in implementation of IPC on a program.
 I've choosed to use the File Mapping method.

Firstly, I need that a process write some data on the memory block that i've created previously.
Then, an other process access this file mapping, read the content and write new content on the memory block.
To finish, a third process access the file mapping and read the content.

Example : 
- The first process write "**UNLOCK**".
- The second process read "**UNLOCK**" and write "**LOCK**" on the file mapping.
- The third process read "**LOCKCK**".

So, I want to erase the file mapping content before write. I found nothing about that, the only solution that I found is to close the file mapping but I need to keep it alive.
Actually, the only way that I found to correct my problem is to write "**LOCK__**". (note that underscore refer to space character)
 Thanks to space character, the length of the word is equal than "**UNLOCK**".

There is a method or function to delete the file mapping content, please ?

PM.

Comment: Zero out all the bytes and `truncate` might work here?

Comment: As anywhere in computing, there is no empty space; you have to fill out with zeroes - or whatever you consider empty data.

Comment: for what you need "erase" the file mapping content before write ? simply write your data

Comment: @Brandon, I will tried that, thanks you.

Comment: @RbMm, if i write my new data without erasing and the new data that i want to write are longer than the old data. So in the file mapping, the data start with the new data and at the end, there is older value.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, i take note, thanks

Comment: @P.Maestro - you not need "erase" old data in any case. you simply bad design your data fotmat. if want zero end string - so simply write it as is. again - erase - senseless

Comment: @RbMm Yes, you are right. If i understand, you all suggest to me to manage the end of my data with zeroes. I will do that, Thanks :)